# Quando tiver no Fragment uma referência através do getActivity() devo usar interface?

Tags: android, android-fragment, interface

Minha duvida é saber qual o melhor modo de se trabalhar para a organização dos métodos, vou apresentar 2 opções de implementação que estou na duvida, ***sempre que eu tiver no Fragment uma referência através do getActivity() devo usar interface?***:

**1º opção :** 
Estou declarando diretamente no Fragment o **getActivity()**:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mensagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**2º opção :**
Criei uma **interface** com o método:

```
public void mensagemToast();
```

Depois na **Activity** implementei esse método usando agora o **this(Activity)**:

```
@Override
    public void mensagemToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "mensagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Depois criei um **listener no Fragment** para chamar esse método que está implementado na 
Activity:

```
listener.mensagemToast();
```

> Esse é só um exemplo tenho vários casos parecidos com este que no Fragment chamo diretamente o **getActivity()**. **Qual a
>   melhor forma dentre as opções que apresentei?**
>
> > **1ª que parece ser mais
> >     simples mas, está pegando uma referência direta da Activity?**
> >     **2ª que é mais burocrática porém desacoplada(separada) do Fragment?**
> >     **Ou existe uma outra solução que seja melhor do que as apresentadas acima?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um ***fragment*** deve ser implementado de forma a ser auto-suficiente, deve poder funcionar/conseguir o seu objectivo por si só.
Seguindo este principio o ***fragment*** pode ser utilizado por qualquer ***activity***.

Este é um dos principais benefícios de se usar ***fragments***.

Para isso, a chamada de métodos da ***activity*** por parte do ***fragment***, deve ser feita apenas no intuito de informar a ***activity*** de que algo aconteceu, devendo, para esse efeito, ser definida uma ***interface*** que a ***activity*** deverá implementar.

O ***fragment*** pode então verificar se a ***activity*** que o criou implementa ou não a ***interface***, decidindo se aceita ou não ser criado.
No primeiro caso, não chama nenhum dos métodos da interface.
No segundo, lança uma excepção.

Nos meus ***fragments*** nunca utilizo `getActivity()`. Se necessito de um *Context*, obtenho-o no método `onAttach()`, se necessito de comunicar com a Activity, faço-a implementar uma *interface*.

A minha abordagem é a seguinte:

Declaro a `interface` e dois atributos na classe derivada de `Fragment`

```
public interface Container{
    //Métodos que as actividades devem implementar
}
private Container container;
private Context context;
```

No método `onAttach()` esses atributos são usados para guardar o `context` e uma referência à *interface* implementada na *activity* que criou o *fragment*

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    if(activity instanceof Container){
        container = (Container) activity; //Guarda uma referência à actividade(interface)
    }
    else{
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                  + " A actividade deve implementar a interface Container");
    }

    context = activity; //Guarda context.

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Quando necessito de um *context* uso o atributo `context`.
Quando necessito de chamar um método da *activity* uso `container.nomeMetodo();`

Veja a documentação do **android** no que diz respeito ao [Design Philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design)

Comment: hum... muito bom sua resposta... mas ainda estou com duvidas só na parte de escolher entre usar sem/com interface no exemplo que eu dei.. ou seja na minha pergunta devo escolher a 1º opção ou a 2ª?

Comment: 2ª opção - Usar uma ***interface***

Comment: blz vlw +1 na sua resposta

Comment: so pertubando mais uma vez.. no caso de eu criar um AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); no fragment também seria necessário a criação de uma interface, ou seja, sempre que no fragment usar o getActivity() sempre devo utiizar uma interface?

Comment: Não percebo o que você quer dizer com esse exemplo. Mas, quando você pergunta se *"sempre devo"*, a minha resposta é: **depende do contexto**. Os padrões e as boas práticas não devem ser seguidas apenas porque alguém o diz. O contexto deve ser levado em conta: o beneficio deve ser maior que o custo.