# Como eu armazeno um objeto BluetoothSocket em um Bundle?

Tags: android

Já tentei o .putParcelable e o .putSerializable e não deu certo. Se não for possível fazer isso, é possível eu pegar do sistema um objeto BluetoothSocket já conectado?

Comment: Quer passá-lo para onde?

Comment: eu quero passá-lo de um Fragment para outro

Comment: Será que você necessita mesmo de fazer isso?

Comment: de acordo com a "regra de negócio" que preciso, infelizmente sim, é possível?

Comment: Não sei, julgo que não.

Comment: não é possível nem pegar esse Objeto de conexão de alguma forma? por exemplo, para pegar uma intent, você usa o getIntent, não existe alguma forma de eu buscar do sistema esse BluetoothSocket?

Comment: Não sei, nunca usei. Continuo a achar que não deveria ter essa necessidade de passar o *BluetoothSocket* entre fragments. Esses *fragments* têm uma *activity* em comum? Se tiverem então o código referente ao BluetoothSocket deverá estar nela e ambos os fragments usam ele.

Comment: sim, todos eles estão ligados à uma Activity principal. Como eu faria então para acessar os dados dessa activity?

Comment: Veja se [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37386/2541), [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13761/2541) e [isto](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) ajuda.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda!