# Problema com fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Criei um fragment e estou tentando chamar ele quando clico em um botão, porém dá um erro e aparece isso no console

> com.example.gustavo.easypasse.RecargaActivity@30d409a0 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

E aponta para essa linha do código:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Como corrijo isso?

Answer (score 2):

A activity, à qual esse fragment é associado, tem de implementar a interface *OnFragmentInteractionListener*.

Ou seja, tem de declarar a Activity desta forma:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    .....
    .....
}
```

e depois implementar os respectivos métodos.

Normalmente a interface é declarada no Fragment e é usada para comunicar com a Activity, daí a obrigatoriedade de esta a implementar.

Alguns exemplos de uso dessa abordagem:

- [Fazer duas classes diferentes se comunicarem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13755/2541)
- [Colocando evento de clique no botão que está numa Fragment, em uma Activity?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97389/2541)
- [Quando tiver no Fragment uma referência através do getActivity() devo usar interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37372/2541)

Comment: E como devo implementar? kkkk

Comment: Se você que criou o Fragment não sabe, como posso eu saber se não conheço o código dele?

Comment: Primeira vez que trabalho com Fragment kkkk Não sei como implementar.

Comment: Foi você que escreveu o código desse Fragment?

Comment: Na verdade eu só criei e montei a telas desse fragment, o Android Studio quem montou a Activity dela.

Comment: Ok. Se não necessita de comunicar com a Activity elimine o método `onAttach()`, caso contrário veja os exemplos que adicionei à resposta. Lembre que eu não tenho a capacidade de adivinhar o que você pretende fazer :)

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa @GustavoSevero, recomendo a leitura [deste artigo](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=en-us), da própria doc do Android Studio, ao invés de usar a técnica DLSF (Dar de louco e sair fazendo)