# Inicializar elemento de um fragmento em outro

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho dois fragmentos ligados a minha activity.

A minha duvida é ,  como inicializo um elemento que esta em outro fragmento?

Em um fragmento, para acessar a activity eu utilizo o código

```
Textview tv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

este funciona, mas e para iniciar um que esteja ligado ao fragmento e não a activity ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Activity como intermediária entre os fragments(fragmentA e fragmentB).

- Declare um método no fragmentA, aquele cujo TextView quer alterar:

  ```
  public void setText(String text){

      textView.setText(text);
  }
  ```
- Declare um método na activity que chame o do fragmentA:

  ```
  public void setFragmentATextView(String text){
      fragmentA.setText(text);
  }
  ```
- No fragmentB chame o método da activity:

  ```
  getActivity().setFragmentATextView("qualquer coisa");
  ```

  <sub>**Nota:** A chamada a métodos da Activity deverá ser feita através de uma [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37372/2541) e não por `getActivity().nomeMetodo()`.</sub>